# Error whyle waiting for device : Unknown error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I want to launch emulator in the Android Studio but i have this error "Error while waiting for device : Unknown error", I turned off windows defender at all but it did not help. Do anyone know what is it and how to fix it ?

I turned off windows deffender at all but it did not help.

[image]